# PHP, MYSQL: Select inside a while Loop?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am requesting your advice about the following:

I have two tables:

Customers and Orders.

I am printing the data of customers inside a table using a while loop:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM wccrm_customers where status = '1' order by date desc";
 $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);

 while ($daten = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
 echo $daten[id];
 echo $daten[name] . ' ' . $daten[vorname];
 echo $daten[email];
 echo $daten[telefon];

 } ?>
```

Now I try to add a new field in this list: Purchased YES/NO. As we have more customers then buyers, we want to show whether someone has bought or not:

The Connection between this two tables is the first/lastname in both tables!

So if customer.name = orders.name and customer.firstname = orders.firstname I want to echo "YES" if not then "NO"

I tried with a JOIN, but here I just get the results who are in both table:

```
SELECT *
FROM wccrm_customers AS k
INNER JOIN wccrm_orders AS o
ON o.namee = k.name AND o.firstname = k.firstname
```

but I need to have all of the customers and the ones who are in both lists marked...

Is this possible? If yes: How can I achieve this?

Thank's for your advice!

Kind regards,

Stefan

Comment: Please, note that `mysql_*` function are deprecated. Take a look to [MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](https://secure.php.net/pdo).

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with PHP, or with while loops; you just need to form your join properly:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
   `k`.*,
   `o`.`namee` IS NOT NULL AS `Purchased`
FROM `wccrm_customers` AS `k`
LEFT JOIN `wccrm_orders` AS `o`
ON
    `o`.`namee` = `k`.`name`
AND `o`.`firstname` = `k`.`firstname`
```

[image: Inner join venn diagram] [image: Left join venn diagram]

Read more about the different join types: http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/

<sup>*(images courtesy of that site, which also contains an example and discussion of almost exactly what you're trying to do!)*</sup>

---

By the way, you must have missed the [massive red warning banner](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) in the manual about using the deprecated (now removed) `mysql_*` functions. You should stop doing that! Use [MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](https://secure.php.net/pdo) instead.

Comment: Great - thank you very much! I am currently working on exchanging all the deprecated syntax....

Comment: @Bosstone: Good stuff. Have fun!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I asked myself that same question. Sure wasn't me, but *au contraire* ;-)

Answer (score -2):

a shorter one

```
SELECT DISTINCT k.*, IF(o.namee IS NULL, 'no', 'yes') purchased
FROM 
  wccrm_customers AS k 
  LEFT JOIN wccrm_orders AS o USING (namee,firstname)
```

Comment: [This is the wrong join type](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f94e/2/0). I applaud the brevity though, even if I would never drop the backticks in production code.

Comment: copy paste mistake, using backticks even when it's useless can be a choice

Comment: We had a production version fail to install on a new customer system, literally three weeks ago, because somebody had written a query that did not use backticks (which unfortunately fell through the code review net in the last release — I would not have okayed it had I spotted it) and the word had become a keyword in the new MySQL version. Had to release an emergency patch, which threw our main release cycle out a bit and caused some logistical headaches. It's not just style; it's rigour. Sadly it is also kind of ugly.

Comment: [Now you need to add `DISTINCT`.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f94e/6/0) (honestly, just _test it_ before posting...!)